# How to add new serializer field along with the all model fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here I have a model which has so many fields. So I want to use `__all__` to return all the fields. But now I needed to add new field `image_url` so I customize a serializer like this but now with this I need to put all the model fields in the `Meta` class like this `fields=['name','..', 'image_url']` in order to return the `image_url`.

Is there any way to return `image_url` without specifying it in the `Meta.fields` ?
I mean I don't want to write all the model fields in the `Meta.fields` (since the fields are too many) and want to return the `image_url` also.

serializers.py

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.fields] + ['image_url']
    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to subclass te serializer:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


class MyChildSerializer(MySerializer):

    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = MySerializer.Meta.fields + ['image_url']

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url
```

Never tried something like this, but since `Meta.fields` is a list you can perform basic python operations on it.

ps. If you're using pattern `get_<field_name>` for getter, you do not need to specify it in SerializerMethodField arguments.

Comment: It does not work.